# Multiple text cursors in stack snippets?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Today I noticed that Stack Snippets support multiple text cursors. Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking into a new line places a secondary cursor (at least in FF 53.0):

**Screenshot:**

[image: Multiple Cursors]

While this might be a hidden niche feature for e.g. formatting or manual loop unrolling, I don't think it is intended behavior - or is it?

I couldn't find any discussion regarding this on meta, searching for "stack snippet" and "cursor" yields nothing.

Comment: Firefox has a long and checkered history of caret bugs.  Do try this in another browser to compare.

Comment: @HansPassant I can at least confirm it is in Chrome v58.0.3029.81.

Comment: [feature-request] implement this everywhere.

Comment: More seriously, if you believe it is a bug, then I think it should be raised to [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/index.html) lib, which doesn't seem to expose an option to force a single cursor. Btw @HansPassant, I don't think there remains anything from native browser's implementations in there.

Comment: Sounds like a deliberate behaviour to me. Sublime Text has exactly this feature, and probably some other editors do too. (And it's very useful!)

Comment: @MarkAmery You might be right. However, I found it irritating when selecting separate words by holding [Ctrl] and then cutting them via [Ctrl] + [x] and having to deal with multiple unexpected "left-over" cursors afterwards.

Comment: @Kaiido +1 because I want this in everything I use. OpenOffice, Visual Studio, Bash, my social life, everything!

Comment: @QPaysTaxes This extension gives this for Visual Studio (but uses Alt instead of Ctrl). I use it all the time! https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode

Comment: @mrsundquist Ooh, that's nice. Visual studio has... something, but it only allows a bunch of cursors in the same column, doesn't let you move it with the arrow keys, etc. etc. (it's bad.) This is gonna be great!

Comment: But does it work? I mean, if you type a letter, does it appear on all four positions? If not, then it's a bug (which can be resolved either way). If it is, then it's a feature, just like in Sublime Text =)

Comment: Why would this not be intended behaviour? You can click anywhere to dismiss multiple cursors, so if you activate this unintentionally, it’s not hard to deal with….

Comment: @justhalf looking at the screenshot it seems to work.

Comment: 'We have discovered the hidden feature' 'Cursors!'

Comment: [Looks like a feature](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/778), smells like a feature, so I guess it is a feature? Even if it was a bug, I would say "it's not a bug, it's a feature".

Answer (score 6):

As [@Kaiido](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) and [@g00glen00b](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1915448/g00glen00b) pointed out in the comments *([Ref 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348604/multiple-text-cursors-in-stack-snippets#comment469728_348604), [Ref 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348604/multiple-text-cursors-in-stack-snippets#comment470155_348604))*, this is a [feature of CodeMirror](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/778).

And it is a great feature! It took me by surprise at first, as I didn't expect being gifted additional text cursors after performing a multi-selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. That's why I posted this question here on meta, in disbelief. It seemed too good to be a feature, it couldn't be, I had never heard or even thought of it. But since then I have come to love the ability to perform all kinds of parallel text manipulations in a single step, by using multiple text cursors. I started answering questions just so I could watch these little bustling carets spouting text here and there. It feels incredibly productive. And it is!

Hopefully, this question will allow more people to discover this handy little feature. I will tag it as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

---

*Edit: Only moderators can tag it as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), so we will have to wait a little bit.*